# LINQ to SQL defining Where class depending on parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
return (from s in db.StudentMarks
                where s.Class == Class && s.Year == Year // this line
                orderby s.Year, s.ExamType
                select new StudentAddMarks()
                {
                    --Obj
                 }).ToList();
```

I am going to return an `Object` depending on the `Class` and `Year` params. I want to remove the `where` condition when the `Class` and `Year` parames are `null` or `zero`.

Any ideas please.

Comment: You should edit your question and use the code formatting tools so that it is more readable. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I'm a little confused - do you want to remove the `where` clause only when both Class and year are `null` or `zero`, or when either is `null` or `zero`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
where (s.Class == Class && s.Year == Year) || Class == null || 
       Class == 0 || Year == null || Year == 0
```

Comment: I dont want to execute the where condition if the vlaues are 0

Comment: Any or all of the values? Is `null` not a concern?

Comment: Thanks a lot 
I got the concept and answer. I appreciaet your help

Answer (score 3):

Just add a clause handling `null` or zero values as well:

```
where ((Class != null && Class != 0) ? s.Class == Class : true) &&
      ((Year  != null && Year  != 0) ? s.Year  == Year  : true)
```

The above code uses the shorthand `if`-`then`-`else` syntax, that works as follows:

```
value = (condition ? if_true : if_false);
// ...is equivalent to...
if (condition)
{
    value = if_true;
}
else 
{
    value = if_false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Your Answer helped me a lot.
                                   result = (from p in GetAllStudentMarksList()
                                             where (collection.SearchClass != null ? p.Class == collection.SearchClass : true) && (collection.SearchYear!=0?p.Year == collection.SearchYear:true)
                                           select p).ToList();